# Torque in 3 dimensional coordinates

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque

[image]

Why is the force's component's torque on its axis is zero? 
In this picture these three forces are the components of one force.
The torque of $F_x$ on the $x$ axis is zero. I want to know why? 
My book says that this is because $F_x$ is parallel to the $x$ axis but I can't understand why? Can someone visualise it to me or something?

Comment: How do you define torque?

Comment: Or better yet, _where_ do you measure torque about?

Answer (score 2):

The torque is defined as $\boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{F}$, from where you can get that $|\boldsymbol{r} \times \boldsymbol{F}|=rF \sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{F}$. By definition $F_x$ is the component of the force in the $x$ direction, then the angle between $F_x$ and $x$ equals $0$ which implies a torque of magnitude $0$.

Answer (score 0):

That is the definition of breaking a vector down to its components.

The Y and Z components of the force would apply a torque to the X axis, but since the X component is parallel to the X axis, they never bisect. Because they never bisect, the X axis would never feel the X component of the force.

This can be applied to all three axes.

Torque is a force times a distance. But since the X component of the force never crosses the X axis anywhere there is no instance where a torque can be felt on the X axis relative to the origin.